# How to get individual variables from a string of user selected checkboxes

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building an advertising directory using WordPress and the HivePress plugin. In the code below, a user chooses which apps they can be contacted on. In the form, there are three checkboxes under social_apps for Telegram, Viber and WhatsApp. In the code below, `$apps = $listing->display_social_apps();` the apps variable will return the results, so in this example (the form code is at the bottom) would display as Viber, WhatsApp. Though if all three are selected it would appear as Telegram, Viber, WhatsApp. What is the best way to break down those three results so that I can make three individual variables from them and without the comma?

If I use explode as shown below, it does separate them into three variables and removes the comma. But the code below only works as I want it to if the user checks all three boxes on submission. So the variable telegram does output Telegram, viber as Viber and whatsapp as WhatsApp. But, if the user chooses only Viber and WhatsApp on the submission form, then the variable telegram outputs Viber. I need for viber to output Viber at all times. As Telegram wasn't chosen by the user, Viber becomes results[0]. How do I stop this from happening? Because the apps variable returns the results, I can't use an array with the values.

```
add_filter(
    'hivepress/v1/templates/listing_view_page/blocks',
    function( $blocks, $template ) {
        $listing = $template->get_context('listing');
        
        if(!$listing){
            return $blocks;
        }
        
    $apps = $listing->display_social_apps();
        
        $results = explode(',', $apps);
          $telegram = $results[0];
          $viber = $results[1];
          $whatsapp = $results[2];
    

        return hivepress()->template->merge_blocks(
                    $blocks,
                    [
                        'page_sidebar' => [
                                'blocks' => [
                                    'custom_text_apps' => [
                            'type' => 'content',
        'content' => '<p><strong>'.$telegram.' and '.$viber.' and '.$whatsapp.'</strong></p>',
                                        '_order' => 12,
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                ]
                );
        },
    
    1000,
    2
);



<div class="hp-form__field hp-form__field--checkboxes"><label class="hp-field__label hp-form__label"><span>Apps</span> <small>(optional)</small></label><div class="hp-field__description">Select the apps you can be contacted on.</div><div class="hp-field hp-field--checkboxes"><ul><li><label for="social_apps_6475ffa0ec27c" class="hp-field hp-field--checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="social_apps[]" id="social_apps_6475ffa0ec27c" value="46"  ><span>Telegram</span></label></li><li><label for="social_apps_6475ffa0ec377" class="hp-field hp-field--checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="social_apps[]" id="social_apps_6475ffa0ec377" value="45"  checked='checked' ><span>Viber</span></label></li><li><label for="social_apps_6475ffa0ec46f" class="hp-field hp-field--checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="social_apps[]" id="social_apps_6475ffa0ec46f" value="35"  checked='checked' ><span>WhatsApp</span></label></li></ul></div></div>
```

Explode was used. It works only when all three checkboxes are selected.

Comment: Instead of assuming that the telegram flag is the first in your array (using `$telegram = $results[0]`) you could instead search for the particular value that indicates telegram using something like `$telegram = in_array(46, $results) ? 46 : false` (and likewise for viber and whatsapp)

Comment: @RobEyre Thanks very much. But it doesn't work with the number. If I change it to Telegram instead of 46 then it outputs Telegram, which is great.  But when I do the same for Viber and WhatsApp it still only outputs the first one. So if Telegram isn't selected but Viber and WhatsApp are, then it only outputs Viber. If all three are selected on submission, then only Telegram shows. Any idea why? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please can you share the exact content of `$results` when all three are selected, and when just Viber and WhatsApp are selected?  Then we can refine the solution.

Comment: @RobEyre Thanks for the reply. I used your code, but changed the number 46 to Telegram. Then $viber as Viber, not 45 etc. When all three are selected $telegram outputs as Telegram and the other two don't have any output at all, so displays as Telegram and and. When Viber and WhatsApp are selected only Viber displays, so it appears as: and Viber and. WhatsApp only displays when it's the only one selected.

Comment: $results = explode(',', $apps);
        $telegram = in_array(Telegram, $results) ? Telegram : false;
        $viber = in_array(Viber, $results) ? Viber : false;
        $whatsapp = in_array(WhatsApp, $results) ? WhatsApp : false;

Comment: From these results it sounds like the variable `$apps` isn't a simple comma separated list.  If you could do `var_dump($apps)` in a couple of scenarios that might help identify what format it is using

Comment: @RobEyre Thank you so much Rob. You were spot on, I changed the explode to ', ' with a space after the comma. The values are indeed separated by a comma and a space. Thanks Rob, that's really kind of you to help and spot the problem.

Comment: @RobEyre I hope I'm OK to ask you another question? I have another field which will have about 20 checkboxes, a user might check less. It will do the same as the apps one above and the variable will output all those checked. They will also be separated by a comma and a space, just like the apps one. I will again use explode to remove the comma and space. Is there a way to display all that are checked, lets say as a list without using all that code for each one? I tried standard print_r and also foreach but they don't work.  Otherwise I will need to list 20 variables.

Comment: You could just loop over your `$results` array.  If you're unclear how to, I suggest you raise another question in SO and show your input (`$results`) and desired output (some kind of rendered list?).